# Retrieve Recordset Populate Array and Output onto Worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, output, worksheet, recordset

After all of these years, I've seen several questions that asks how to populate an Array with a Recordset, but none that addresses how to write the output onto a worksheet all in one procedure.  So, I decided to ask the Question in order to provide an answer that I've developed over time.

Comment: Just wanted to check if you were aware of the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method? Do you need the step of creating an array when the recordset can be written directly to a range?

Answer (score 0):

```
'Goes on Top
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Option Base 1

Public Sub Recordset_to_Array_to_Worksheet()

Dim MyArray() As Variant 'unbound Array with no definite dimensions'
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL as String, Fieldname as String
Dim i as Integer, j as Integer, colcnt as Integer, rowcnt as Integer
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim Dest as Range

'------------------------RECORDSET------------------------'
Set db = Opendatabase("URL link") 'or Set db = Currentdb()
strSQL = "SQL Statement Here"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strsQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If rst.recordcount <> 0 then '///Do NOT Use "Do While Not rst.EOF" Can cause Problems///'
    colcnt = rst.Fields.Count-1
    rowcnt = rst.recordcount
 Else
    Exit Sub
End IF

'-----------------------------WRITE RECORDSET TO MYARRAY----------------------------'
ReDim MyArray (rowcnt, colcnt) 'Redimension MyArray parameters to fit the SQL returned'
rst.MoveFirst

'Populating Array with Headers from Recordset'
For j = 0 To colcnt
     MyArray(0,j) = rst.Fields(j).name
Next

'Populating Array with Record Data
For i = 1 to rowcnt
    For j = 0 to colcnt
        MyArray(i,j) = rst(j)
    Next J
    rst.movenext
Next i

'---------------------------------WORKSHEET OUTPUT---------------------------------'
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Insert Worksheet Name")
Set Dest = ws.Range("A1") 'Destination Cell
Dest.Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1) + 1, UBound(MyArray, 2) + 1).value = 
Application.Transpose(MyArray) 'Resize (secret sauce)

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - there is a lot that could be optimized, e.g. you can use recordset.getRows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao), use subs per task (getRecordset, getArrayFromRecordset, writeArrayToRange) etc. to build a more generic code

Comment: @Ike  I don't think you can use   '.GetRows' for this unless you're willing to transpose the data when populating the Array.  But, I will definitely post this on Codereview as you suggest.

Comment: Yes - you have to use transpose - but that's no issue - I am doing that all the time with huge recordsets.

Comment: @Ike, No.  You don't understand.  You'd have to Create an entirely separate Public Function --> TransposeArray(InputArr As Variant) As Variant.  It's inefficient to create a 2nd SubRoutine just transpose the data as it's populating an array.  No one would do that for this case.

Comment: Why not? - One of my main programming rules is: one function/routine = one task - with that I have a lot of routines that are pretty small - but can be re-used and individually tested.